# How to display json data using angular datatable dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, angular-material

How to call multiple api and display data using angular material datatable dynamically.
since am new to angular, I would like to know with some examples.

Comment: Try something like datatables or tabulator. Good 3rd party libraries to begin with..

Comment: @MSzucs thanks for reply, but want to try in angular material

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng2-smart-table](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table).

It works great.

I use it alot in production with MEAN and Electron.